# How can I solve the pytorch/pylint error: torch.tensor is not callable?

Tags: pytorch, pylint, federated-learning

when I make in python

```
import syft as sy
import torch

hook = sy.TorchHook(torch)
data = torch.tensor([[1.,1],[0,1],[1,0],[0,0]])
```

an error came up that says: 'torch.tensor is not callable'. And I do not know how to solve it.
I have pytorch version 1.4.0.

Comment: Maybe [that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NPlEL.png) would explain it!